# Modificar varias tablas con un join

Tags: php, mysql

Actualmente en mi proyecto poseo 5 tablas que están relacionadas entre sí mediante una serie de claves primarias y foráneas. Ahora tengo una sección donde puedo modificar los datos de todas las tablas pero quisiera hacerlo con un inner join. ¿Es esto posible?, ¿o debo hacerlo tabla por tabla respetando sus claves foráneas?

Answer (score 0):

Sí, se pueden actualizar múltiples tablas, tal cual se específica en [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

Ejemplo:

```sql
UPDATE Tabla_A a 
 INNER JOIN Tabla_B b 
    ON (a.id = b.id) 
   SET 
       a.campo = 4321, 
       a.ediciones = a.ediciones+1, 
       a.autor = "Nombre", 
       b.texto = "xyz",
       b.votos = 9
 WHERE a.id = 1;
```